# How can I stringify almost-valid json in python

Tags: json, mongodb, libgdx

My android game pushes this JSON to my django server:

```
{
data: [
    [
        Settings,
        "4748"
    ]
],
logType: starcycle-screenchanges
}
```

It's not valid though because it doesn't have the strings. Which, I think, is why I can't insert it into mongoDB. Is there an easy way to make it so I can make it a json with json.loads().

I can't use eval()

Comment: The game is written in libgdx, and I'm preferring to use their API for converting to Json. Their API converts my log objects into those quoteless strings instead of valid json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data seems to be valid [YAML](http://yaml.org/) (which is a superset of JSON), so you can use [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML):

```
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.load(data)
{'data': [['Settings', '4748']], 'logType': 'starcycle-screenchanges'}
```

Comment: Not all of my not-quote-json objects were valid in yaml, but you definitely set me on the right track. Thanks.

Comment: The problem ended up being with libgdx's encoding of json objects. As described here, json is not the default for Json objects. Silly. https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=1097